# Jquery selector issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I have the following html markup on my page,

```
<div id="sig_container">
    <div id="layer1" class="layer ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide">
    <div id="layer2" class="layer ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide">
    <div id="layer3" class="layer ui-draggable ui-resizable selected ui-resizable-autohide">
</div>
```

On this page I am trying to select the #sig_container div without selecting any of the children. However I am having an issue doing so. The selector either selects everything or nothing.

Thanks in advance
Daniel

Edit: Sorry i should add I am trying to add a click event on the container. So i want the event to fire only when i click the container and not the children.

Comment: That doesn't make sense - what do you want to do with the container?

Comment: $('#sig_container')  Should select the element. What does alert($('#sig_container').html()); give you?

Comment: When you select an element, you'll also get that element's children as part of the object.  Why is it a problem that you're getting the children as well as the parent?  Are you trying to delete the parent?

Comment: you're going about it like, right? $("div#sig_container")

Comment: Sorry i have corrected my post, i am trying to fire and event not get the HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by testing the `event.target` of the click event.

```
$('#sig_container').click(function( event ) {
    if( event.target === this ) {
        // the children were not clicked, so run your code
    }
});
```

The reason for this is that click events naturally bubble, so if you click one of the children, the event bubbles up to the `sig_container` and fires its handler.

With this solution, you make sure that the `target` of the event was actually the `sig_container` before it fires the code.

So basically:

- `this` is the `sig_container`
- `event.target` is the actual element clicked
- if `this` is the same as the `event.target` run the code

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for and sorry to the people he answered before my edit. Have an +1 anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This selector will select **only** the `<div id="sig_container">`:

```
$('#sig_container')
```

If you think it's selecting the children as well, it's not:

```
alert($('#sig_container').length); // alerts 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sig_container')
```

should do the trick.  If it doesn't, are you passing the html through anything that mangles IDs?